# Angular 2 @Output parameters

Tags: angular

Im trying to pass parameters through @Output but the fired function just receive 'undefined'. Can someone please show me the way to pass parameters through the EventEmitter of the @Output? For Example:

```
var childCmp = ng.core.Component({
             selector:'child-cmp',
             outputs: ['myEvent']
             }).Class({
               constructor: function(){
                            this.myEvent = new ng.core.EventEmitter();
                            this.myEvent.emit(false);
                            }
             });
var parentCmp = ng.core.Component({
              selector:'parent-cmp',
              template:'<child-cmp (myEvent)="invoke()"'></child-cmp>',
              directives: [childCmp]
           }).Class({
                constructor:function(){},
                invoke: function(flag){
                    // here flag is undefined!!
                }
             });
```

Comment: Can you share some code? What is being sent when you call EventEmitter.emit ?

Comment: See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Output-var.html

Comment: I added example for my question

Comment: I have checked their Api, but there is no example with receive parameters from the emitter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You shoud use the following to get the value provided with the event:

```
<child-cmp (myEvent)="invoke($event)"'></child-cmp>'
```

This way the `invoke` method of your `childCmp` will receive as parameter the value you provide when emitting the `myEvent` custom event.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: It is **$event** indeed

Answer (score 6):

Thierry answer is almost correct, you need to pass the **$event** in the output function :

```
<child-cmp (myEvent)="invoke($event)"'></child-cmp>'
```

Comment: In the future you should probably just edit the answer

Comment: Indeed, I didn't knew that time, was 1 year ago ¯\_(ツ)_/¯